# Determining the largest portions of values within an array to match a given value

Tags: php, arrays, math

I have an array with values:

```
$values = array(
    2,
    4,
    7.5,
    9
);
```

And i have a separate value:

```
$total = 12;
```

What's the correct mathematical approach to pick out values from `$values`, with the greater values coming first and the lesser values coming last, until the value of `$total` is reached or closely approached, but never exceeded?

I am aware that this is a basic mathematical problem, but i am pretty incapable of maths, and i have no idea how to accomplish this.

Comment: What you are asking for is solving a Knapsack-Problem, see for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem for more details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Possible Combination of Knapsack problem and?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782453/possible-combination-of-knapsack-problem-and)

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. For a lack of not knowing any keywords, how am i supposed to find those solutions in a pile of millions. Will have a look to see if that's precisely what i am looking for.

Comment: Clearly the "knapsack problem" is an exaggerated version of this, overcomplicating the matter. If the explanations provided in that answer were helpful to me, i would not have needed to ask this one in the first place. I love it when people judge without investigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ironically, i ended up with a fairly compact piece of code, which beautifully solves the problem - and proves that this is not the knapsack problem per sé.

```
$total = 7.9;
$values = array(2, 2.5, 5, 8);
$computed = 0;

rsort($values);

foreach($values as $val) {
    if($val + $computed > $total)
        continue;
    $computed += $val;
}
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

there a working solution for you.

```
<?php
    $values = array(
        2,
        4,
        1.5,
        1,
        3,
        5
    );

    $total = 12;
    rsort($values);
    $newarray = array();
    foreach($values as $key)
    {
        if(array_sum($newarray) == $total)
        {
            array_pop($newarray);
            break;
        }
        else if(array_sum($newarray) > $total)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            $newarray[] = $key;
        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: Thank you, Dipen. I have to look into it, but it looks decent. What i see in this code is that the resulting array values may exceed `$value` though, but that could easily be changed.

Comment: My bad I read it incorrectly. I thought it was okay to have equal values but its a minor fix I suppose.

Comment: Equal, yes, but not exceeding. Still grateful for the addition though :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$minimum = 5;$maximum = 8;
```

---

```
$numbers= array(2,4,
7.5,
9
);
```

---

```
$newArray = array_filter($numbers,function ($value) use($minimum ,$maximum ) {        
    return ($value >= $minimum && $value <= $maximum );
});
```